# Limpiar calendario bootstrap-datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Tengo este código html que al elegir un pais me carga los dias en el calendario:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Pais</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="origen" name="origen" required="">
                <option value="">---</option>
                {% for pais in paises %}
                        <option value="{{ pais.code }}">{{ pais.name }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Fecha Salida</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_from" placeholder="Fecha Salida" required="" disabled="">
            <input type="hidden" id="fechaSalida">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Cuando selecciono un paisde origen, lanzo una petición ajax que iniciliza el calendario y mustra unicamente las fechas de salida disponibles, mas o menos asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los que estan en negrita, son los disponibles.

El problema es que si cambio de pais, SIEMPRE salen las mismas fechas disponibles. Pero si refresco la página `ctrl+shif+r` y elijo el pais seleccionado anteriormente si cambian las fechas.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo resetear el calendario?

Mi código ajax, que estaía dentro de un evento `on.('change')`:

```
if (($("#origen").val() != null && !$("#origen").val().equals("") && $("#origen").val() != undefined)
{
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: urlInt + "/salidas/" + $("#origen").val() + "/",
    })
    .success(function(msg) {
        //console.log(JSON.parse(msg));

        var disableIni = JSON.parse(msg);
        var disable = [];
        var lastDate = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < disableIni.length; i++)
        {
            var current = '"' + disableIni[i][0] + '/' + disableIni[i][1] + '/' + disableIni[i][2] + '"';
            //console.log(current);
            disable[i] = moment(current, "MM/DD/YYYY");

            lastDate = moment(current, "MM/DD/YYYY")
        }

        var vector = disable;
        var date = new Date();
        date.setDate(date.getDate());

        $("#input_from").prop('disabled', false);
        $('#input_from').datetimepicker({
            locale: 'es',
            format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
            minDate: date,
            maxDate: lastDate,
            enabledDates: $.each(vector, function(i, value) {
                return value;
            })
        });        
    });
}
```

El plugin que utilizo es: [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Comment: Datetimepicker viene por defecto con bootstrap o es algún plugin de jquery aparte?

Comment: Hola @AlvaroMontoro Es un plugin aparte: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el código que controla el cambio de país o es lo que ya tienes puesto?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Es lo que ya esta puesto, es un evento `on.('change')`

Comment: Te voy a escribir esto en un comentario porque no es una respuesta a tu problema, pero es sobre tu código: en todo el código hay muchas cosas que optimizar pero no le voy a dar importancia, pero el `if` está mal condicionado. según la condición tu `if` va a entrar siempre que no sea `null` O no esté vacío O no sea undefined, es decir, que si está vacío va a entrar ya que no es null, y si es undefined más de lo mismo. La condición debería estar separada por && para que se tengan que cumplir las 3. y también podrías cambiar el ` equals("") != true` por !equals , es lo óptimo.

Comment: Muchas gracias @ErlantzCalvo tienes razón, ahora mismo lo cambio

Comment: @user45237 podrias incluir en el select el evento onchage...ejemplo:  <select class="form-control" id="origen" name="origen" onchange="miFuncion();">

Comment: donde miFuncion llamas a tu metodo para recrear tu codigo del datapicker...antes de recrearlo debes destruirlo como dice la documentacion: $('#input_from').data("DateTimePicker").destroy();

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que destruir el datetimepicker antes de crearlo nuevamente.

Prueba agregando:

```
$('#input_from').data("DateTimePicker").destroy();
```

Antes de

```
$('#input_from').datetimepicker
```

Puedes ver la documentación completa [aquí](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/).

Si te da error comprueba que antes exista el elemento como datetimepicker.

Comment: Me sale este error: `$(...).data(...) is undefined`

Comment: $('#input_from').datetimepicker().destroy()

Comment: Lo mismo: `$(...).datetimepicker(...).destroy is not a function`

Comment: La respuesta de Nicolás es correcta a mi parecer. El error parece estar más en que donde realizas la llamada del código no tienes definido o bien jQuery o bien datetime picker. Esto puede ocurrir si este código está antes de la inclusión de las librerías.

Comment: Esto no funciona, fijate que esta llamando directamente al input y no como en la documentación, donde se lo encierra en un div, el autor del plugin esta mudo ante este problema.